# Installation Office Web Apps on Windows Server 2012 R2 failed

Tags: installation, office-web-apps

I am setting up my Office Web Apps 2013 server on Windows Server 2012 R2.

According [Deploy Office Web Apps Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455.aspx), I installed

- .NET Framework (but installer said the equivalent or later version is already installed)
- Windows Features suggested

Then I start installing Office Web Apps, but it fails with error message that require me to install .Net Framework 4.5.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have .NET 4.6 installed, uninstall it and re-install .NET 4.5. Then try the WAC install again. You can upgrade to .NET 4.6 afterwards.

Comment: I need to install .NET 4.5.2 **BEFORE** installing .NET 4.6 and even **running windows update**.

Answer (score 0):

Install is blocked until removal the update for Microsoft Windows (KB3102467) and restarting the server...

Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Installed Updates > search for KB3102467 > click uninstall

Also, the only documentation I found was from an exchange team blog to repair the 4.5.2 installation after the uninstall of 4.6.1. You will need the offline version of 4.5.2 in order to repair...

-Ivan